# How to choose a Bundt cake pan?

Tags: equipment, cake, pan

I think one would just go to the supermarket and buy whatever, but since I don't want my cakes to be ruined, I would like to ask for some advice.

I have never bought a Bundt cake pan myself, and don't know what kind of materials should I look for, what's the optimal diameter, and eventually if there are some "non-sticking" ones (or even dishwasher-resistant) that do their job. Please notice that I have an electrical oven.

Comment: I personally like the ones w/out too many deep corners in them, as I find they're less forgiving if you don't properly prepare the pan (greasing & flouring, or cake release).  Also, what you're going to be baking is important -- you can cook angel food cake in them, but you want to make sure the center core sticks out above the level of the outer rim.  (so you can invert it and it rests on the core, rather than squishing down the cake; speciality angel food pans will also have legs around the outside edge)

Comment: This is a very nice hint that I didn't account for. Yet, do you have any advice about the diameter and material?

Comment: Diameter & depth are mostly a function of volume, which is based on what you're baking for the most part.  (you can bake a cake in a larger than optimal pan, but the proportions are off ... and in the other direction you have to hold back some of the batter so it doesn't end up mushrooming out like a cupcake).  And for material, I've only used the 'nonstick' coated steel ones, so can't say anything about the new silicone ones or older non-nonstick ones.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The bundt pans come in 6 cups, 10 cups, 12 cups. I'd go with the middle size as most recipes call for a 10 cup pan. Non-stick is best, though I always give it a spray anyway. They are usually made of cast aluminum. I've had no problem with those. As a beginner, stick to a simpler pattern than one with a lot of nooks and crannies.

Comment: Could you please convert the cups in diameter (here in Europe there is no way I'm going to find a "cup-measure")? Can you wash the aluminium pans in the dishwasher?

Comment: We here in the US never learned metrics. LOL! I can only think in terms of cups and inches, so I went to the Amazon UK website and found a 10 cup bundt pan which measures 24 cm diameter x 10 cm height, 2.3 Litre/ 10 cup capacity.

Your pan will tell you how to clean it if you buy a new one. But I rarely wash mine since it is non-stick. I just wipe it with a paper towel. Occasionally I will just wash it in the sink. I don't want to risk getting that dark look that aluminum sometimes gets in the dishwasher.

Comment: You should add this in your answer I guess :P